# navigation issue inside directory with rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory "Users" with 3 files inside it

```
/index.php
/activity.php
/settings.php
```

My rewrite Rule says

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/ users/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now i want to navigate to

```
http://localhost/user/userid/logs
```

So i tried

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/logs users/activity.php [NC,L]
```

But its not working it loads the contents of the index file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your second rewrite rule is after the first. The L flag causes rewrite to stop looking at additional rules once it matches. Basically, the first line:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/ users/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Is matching, and then ignoring the rest. You could try placing the other line above it like so:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/logs users/activity.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/ users/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

You could also remove the L flag, but I don't know what the rest of your htaccess is like, so other rules could supercede.

Or you could also try this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ users/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/logs/?$ users/activity.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: The first example worked and i understood what was causing the issue. Second Example contatin ?$ what does that do?

Comment: The $ is like the ^. Basically it's saying to only match that URL if it ends there. The ? is basically saying the / is optional

Comment: ? = 0 or 1 times (in regular expressions)